# SonarQube does not recognize some Lombok annotations - misleading test coverage results by Jacoco

Tags: java, eclipse, sonarqube, lombok

SonarQube supports partially Lombok annotations (getters - setters etc). However, it does not still support `@EqualsAndHashCode` and `@ToString` methods.

I have tried all answers on StackOverflow and others sites. However, it does not work in my case.

Is there any way to say SonarQube or Jacoco, that do not analyze this annotation(s) or do not include them in test coverage results or what would be your solution to this problem?

Comment: It is not very clear what the problem is exactly: you have issue with lombok and JaCoCo ? or with issues raised by SonarQube java analyzer ? or both ?

Comment: @benzonico I am analyzing my project with "mvn clean verify sonar:sonar" and in the SonarQube Unit Test Coverage part, the percentage of the coverage is seen lower than it should be because of the fact that SonarQube does not recognize  "EqualsAndHashCode" and "ToString" methods, which are generated by Lombok. I would like to exclude these methods from SonarQube Unit Test Coverage results.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your point, but I don't think you can exclude a method from the SonarQube test coverage analysis. You can exclude classes, though.

Comment: @ThiagoPorciúncula Thank you for your answer. I would like to exclude all of the lombok annotations (or let them analyze)  if it is possible.

Comment: Is SonarQube pointing at the Lombok annotations as code not covered by your tests? Is SonarQube raising issues related to the Lombok annotations you're using? What exactly is the problem?

Comment: @ThiagoPorciúncula SonarQube recognizes some of the Lombok-generated methods such as getters and setters, noArgConstructor etc. However, it does not recognizes ToString and EqualsAndHashCode methods, which are generated by Lombok. Normally, the test coverage should be over 90%. However, because of the fact that, SonarQube does not recognizes these Lombok-Generated codes, the coverage is about 70%, which is not correct. I would like to get the actual test coverage percentage by eliminating Lombok-Generated code from SonarQube analysis. That is my aim.

Comment: Is Lombok generated code regular Java code (are they present on your Java files) or are they bytecode only?

Comment: No, they are not present on my java files. (If I am not wrong) it is generated by compile-time and bytecode only.

Comment: If your issue is with coverage and lombok then SonarQube has nothing to do with your problem. Your issues is in your configuration of JaCoCo.

Answer (score 8):

Starting with Jacoco 0.7.10, it is now possible that Lombok-generated code gets excluded by setting the flag `lombok.addLombokGeneratedAnnotation` to `true` in lombok.config.

More on http://www.rainerhahnekamp.com/ignoring-lombok-code-in-jacoco

Comment: Hi! We followed the guide and it is not working in our case. Sonar keeps reporting Lombok code as untested droping the coverage. The versions we use: SonarQube 6.4.0 | Lombok 1.16.18 | Jacoco maven plugin 0.7.10-SNAPSHOT (I even tried the Edge version of Lombok: 1.16.19). Any idea? Thx!

Comment: Sonar will have to update their version internally as soon as Jacoco 0.7.10 is released. More info on that particular topic: https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/pull/513#issuecomment-293176354

Comment: I try to use to use jacoco 0.7.10-SNAPSHOT  but got the same result

Answer (score 4):

Let's put SonarQube out of the equation as it is just the tool revealing the issue.

JaCoCo works by instrumenting bytecode: This means that it adds some instructions (probes) at particular places in bytecode and see which probes are hit during test runs or not.

On its side Lombok generates methods at bytecode level.
Those generated method are then instrumented by JaCoCo and not covered by your tests.

So you would have to configure JaCoCo to ignore those methods, or to instrument classes before lombok does its magic, or write tests for those generated methods.

Answer (score 3):

You can [configure Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/features/configuration.html) to generate `@SuppressFBWarnings` on generated code. Possible, you can configure JaCoCo to listen to that annotation. Unfortunately, `@javax.annotation.Generated`has retention source, so that's no use for you.

Disclosure: I am a Lombok developer

Comment: Since Jacoco 0.7.10/0.8.0 (see rainerhahnekamp's answer) this workaround is no longer needed and should not be used.